# How do I read a newline delimited json file using mmap?

Tags: python, mmap

I am trying to read the Wikidata compressed dump file using Python's mmap module, but I run into the following error. Here is the snippet of the code to read the file:

```py
def read_file(filename):
    with bz2.open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        with mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as mm:
            for line in iter(mm.readline, b""):
                line = line.rstrip(b",\n")
                if line in [b"[", b"]"]:
                    continue
                yield json.loads(line)
```

The format of the dump file is something like this:

```
[

line1,

line2,

]
```

In my function, it fails reading the first line ("[\n") with a unicode decode error.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xac in position 11: invalid start byte
```

Additionally, the loop doesn't terminate. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Note - I can read the file normally, i.e. without using mmap, but that is very very slow.

Comment: Please update your question with the code that runs slowly.

Comment: It is pretty much the same code but without the mmap context reader and a change to the for loop; the for loop would read as `for line in f:` instead of `for line in iter(mm.readline, b"]"): `

Comment: I created a sample of the input file. When the file is uncompressed, the function works fine. So, it is the streaming data from bz2.open() that mmap() cannot read. Is there a workaround for this without having to decompress a 77GB file?

Comment: Search for the error message to get an explanation of what it means.